# Google Maps directions link only shows route preview in iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, google-maps

I am using Google's URL structure for a directions links. The links automatically open the Google Maps app on iOS, but it only shows a route preview - "start navigation" never appears. I can get the start navigation link to appear by clicking the address destination and choosing the address from a drop down, but I don't understand why the exact same address won't trigger Google's navigation by default. Here is an example of one of the links:

```
https://www.google.com/maps?saddr=My+location&daddr=142+Berkeley+Street,+Boston,+MA+02116
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add either the `comgooglemaps://` or `comgooglemaps-x-callback://` URL schemes.

You can about it more over [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/urlscheme#add_navigation_to_your_app)